# Supplying string parameters that may contain special characters to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, escaping

I need to pass strings that **may** contain special characters to a Javascript function as below.

```
function setEditMode(countryName, countryCode)
{
    document.getElementById("txtCountryName").value=countryName;
    document.getElementById("txtCountryCode").value=countryCode;        
}

<input id="txtCountryName" name="txtCountryName" type="text" maxlength="50"/><br/>

<input id="txtCountryCode" name="txtCountryCode" type="text" maxlength="2"/><br/>               

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnEdit" name="btnEdit" onclick="setEditMode('&#039;xx&#039; &#034;yy&#034; # $', '&#034;&#039;');" />
```

When the button is clicked the two parameters of type string that contain special characters need to be supplied to the `setEditMode()` Javascript function. The strings need to be escaped. I have tried using the `escape()` function but it didn't work. Is there a way to pass such parameters to a function? (I'm dealing with JSP).

[Those parameters of the `setEditMode()` function correspond to `'xx' "yy" # $` and `"'`
respectively].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters you show in your sample contains html entities. Are you trying to decode them? There is no native method in Javascript to do that, but you can use the following code snippet (requires jQuery):

```
 $("<div>").html("&#034;").html();
```

In your case:

```
 var countryName = $("<div>").html(countryName).html();
 var countryCode = $("<div>").html(countryCode).html();
```

Or use a generic function:

```
function decodeHtmlEntities(value)
{
   return $("<div>").html(value).html();
}
```

and

```
function setEditMode(countryName, countryCode)
{
    document.getElementById("txtCountryName").value=decodeHtmlEntities(countryName);
    document.getElementById("txtCountryCode").value=decodeHtmlEntities(countryCode);        
}
```

Or use this function: http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode:424
if you're not in the mood for creating div tags with jQuery.

Edit: Based on your comment. Seems to be a problem with entities for `"` and `'` in inline script. You can solve it by calling a method like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnEdit" name="btnEdit" onclick="setEditModeWrapper()" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setEditModeWrapper()
    {
        setEditMode('&#039;xx&#039; &#034;yy&#034; # $', '&#034;&#039;');
    }
</script>
```

And combine this solution with the decoding functions above if you want those ' to be decoded in the input fields.

Or more classy:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submitBtn" id="btnEdit" name="btnEdit" data-countryname="&#039;xx&#039; &#034;yy&#034; # $" data-countrycode="&#034;&#039;" />

<script tyoe="text/javascript">
$(".submitBtn").on("click", function(e)
{
    var btn = $(e.currentTarget);
    var countryName = btn.attr("data-countryname");
    var countryCode = btn.attr("data-countrycode");
    setEditMode(countryName, countryCode);
});
</script>
```

Place the script tag at the bottom of the page and it will handle all your submit buttons based on their data-countryname and data-countrycode attributes. Render them in the same way  you render your data in the onclick handler.

Comment: The `setEditMode()` funtion **itself** is not being called because of special characters in its parameters `setEditMode('&#039;xx&#039; &#034;yy&#034; # $', '&#034;&#039;');`. How can I invoke it? Internet Explorer says `Expected')'`.

Comment: How did you pass parameters to `setEditMode('...', '...')`? Could you please show me?

Comment: Try the code I added in my edit. Seems to be a problem with entities for " and ' in inline script. It will work if you move it to a function like above. A bit more verbose though.

Comment: Those values (parameters of `setEditMode()`) are arriving from the *database*. Therefore, I need to pass them as soon as the button is clicked. [i.e the parameters are determined at run time].

Comment: That should be no problem. Just render the parameters in setEditModeWrapper() instead of in the <input>. How does your code that render the values from the database look?

Comment: When a page is loaded, an HTML table is dynamically populated from the database.There is a submit button in one of the columns of the HTML table [the button shown here `type=button` is just as an example]. When this button is clicked, the values in the remaining columns of the HTML table of the row corresponding to this button are passed as parameters to this function `setEditMode()`. The approach is working just fine but certain special characters would need to be escaped, if they *were to* arrive from the database.

Comment: I think that the last "Or more classy" solution will suit you, based on how you are rendering the data today.

Comment: Great question. I didn't know about these issues with entities and inline scripting.

Comment: I have decided to use another approach on the server-side to escape HTML using the class [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) of [`Apache Commons Lang`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). Thank you very much for your time.